# ModelMapper конвертер для вложенных объектов

Tags: java, spring, mapper

Конфигурация маппера

```
@Component
public class ModelMapperFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<ModelMapper> {

    @Autowired
    private Collection<MapperConfigurer> configurers;

    @Override
    public ModelMapper getObject() {

        final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configurers)) {
            configurers.forEach(c -> c.configure(modelMapper));
        }

        return modelMapper;
    }      

}
```

Пример конвертера

```
 @Component
public class ModelConverter implements MapperConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(ModelMapper modelMapper) {

        modelMapper.addConverter(new AbstractConverter<ModelEntity, Model>() {

            @Override
            protected Model convert(ModelEntity source) {

                return Model.builder()
                        .id(source.getId())
                        .name(source.getName())
                        .serverConfig(modelMapper.map(source.getServerConfig(), ServerProcessConfig.class))
                        .build();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Spring приложение, в котором ипользую маппер. Для каждых сущностей есть свой конвертер. Есть для Model. есть и для ServerProcessConfig.

При конвертации model я вызывают modelmapper и вызываю у него метод map чтобы сконвертировать вложенный объект, для которого тоже есть реализованный конвертер.

Соответственно, я ожидаю, что маппер будет использоваться его. Однако, очевидно маппер его не использвует(брекпоинт не срабатывает) а пробует преобразовать объект так, судя по всему, просто по сопостовлению полей.

Если попробовать просто (не в качестве вложенного объекта) преобразовать ServerProcessConfig, то реализованный для этого конвертер сработает как положенно.

Почему маппер не использует другие конверторы для вложенных объктов?

Comment: а вы зарегали в маппере эти конвертера?

Comment: конечно. я в описании уточнил, что если конвертировать ServerProcessConfig напрямую (не как вложенный объект), то все проходит как надо - используется нужный конвертер.

Answer (score 0):

конвертация documentDTO в document, у которого есть вложенное поле employee:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(EmployeeDTO.class, Employee.class);
modelMapper.map(documentDTO, Document.Class);
```

Comment: У меня такой вариант не работает